# Laravel Dropbox Fire Upload- InvalidArgumentException in Checker.php line 22:

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, dropbox-api

I want to upload file with dropbox Api using Laravel. I have used following Code for uploading from my drive to dropbox. But while Uploading I'm getting following Error:

> ```
> InvalidArgumentException in Checker.php line 22:
> 'inStream' has bad type; expecting resource, got Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile
> ```

If anyone faced or solved the problem, help me to solve it please.

Here is my controller code:

```
   public function dropboxFileUpload()
        {
            $Client = new Client(env('DROPBOX_TOKEN'), env('DROPBOX_SECRET'));

                  $dropboxFileName='';
                   $file = Input::file('image');

                $size = Input::file('image')->getSize();
                $name = Input::file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
                $dropboxFileName = '/'.$name;


            $Client->uploadFile($dropboxFileName,WriteMode::add(),$file, $size);
            $links['share'] = $Client->createShareableLink($dropboxFileName);
            $links['view'] = $Client->createTemporaryDirectLink($dropboxFileName);

            print_r($links);
        }
```

Here is the route part:

```
Route::post('dropboxFileUpload', 'ImportController@dropboxFileUpload');
```

And here is the view part:

```
<form style="border: 4px solid #a1a1a1;margin-top: 15px;padding: 10px;" action="{{ URL::to('dropboxFileUpload') }}" class="form-horizontal" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
            <input type="file" name="image" />
              {!! Form::token(); !!}
            {!!   csrf_field() ; !!} 
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Import File</button>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try

```
$Client->uploadFile($dropboxFileName,WriteMode::add(),$file, $size, null, true);
```

It's used for indication if the file is for testing purposes. This will skip validation.

Second thing is to check if you create object of `\Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile` and not `\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile`

Comment: Same Error I'm getting!

Comment: Same Error I'm getting actually and yes I've used `use Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile;` namespace in controller